# Does a cold spare Cisco ASA we need a separate license to keep it up to date?

Tags: cisco-asa

We have 2 ASA 5505's. The one that is in production does have a current contract on it, but the second one is a spare so we did not renew it since it was replaced with a 5512 at another location. Since the production ASA 5505 has been kept up to date, in the event of a failure I would like to have a "drop in" replacement until the support contract ships a replacement. Am I able to legally update the firmware on the spare device without purchasing an additional licensing contract or is there a different type of contract that I need to purchase or am I forced into paying for a full contract even though it's going to sit on a shelf collecting dust until the production one fails, that is if it ever does fail?

What are my options and where can I verify if anything isn't needed as an additional cost?

Comment: You really should have a hot failover.  In other words, no single point of failure.  ...Just sayin.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just received the following response from Cisco:
"Upgrading the version of the ASA is not related to any licenses, therefore as long as you can download the desired image from cisco.com you will be able to upload it on the device in question and upgrade."

And another response further clarifying:

"If you are not using any licensed features, I do not see an issue swapping two devices, since they are both 5505 and would have the same config and version.

In addition, here are some links regarding 5505 memory requirements and upgrade path (depends on what version it is currently on):
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/security/asa-5500-series-next-generation-firewalls/product_bulletin_c25-586414.html

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa92/upgrade/upgrade92.html
"

Answer (score 0):

Legally? Not. you should have a support contract for each device.
But I don't think so that this is enforced in anyway.

On April 13, 2017 there is End of Service Contract Renewal Date. And last date of support is: January 31, 2018. So I would suggest upgrade to 5506.

More information you can obtain on this site: [Order Services](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/services/order-services.html)

Comment: Legally and surprisingly, yes Cisco does allow this since they will be servicing the one device that is covered and the one that is not covered they are NOT servicing.

Comment: Oh I was wrong than, I've been told by my Cisco reseller that to legally patch any IOS or ASA I would require support for each device.

Comment: The only thing that you would be losing is any "licensed" features, but they mentioned in the event that it was used as a bridge device when working with TAC to mention that you have a cold spare and to request transfer of licensed features if you need them to be functional until the new unit arrives. They said that there may be licensing fees or transfer fees but did not know off hand and stated that sales would have to be looped in to discuss further. We don't use any licensed features so it's not a concern for us.